# Haskell serialport retrieve data and print

Tags: haskell, serial-port

I'm trying the Serialport package to send some AT commands to COM6

```
 import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
 import System.Hardware.Serialport

 let port = "COM6"          -- Windows

 s <- openSerial port defaultSerialSettings { commSpeed = CS2400 }
 send s $ B.pack "AT\r"
 recv s 10 >>= print
 closeSerial s
```

Does `recv s 10 >>= print` show me the result of the sent command?
I have tried a few AT commands and couldn't get results.
I'm sure that the openport has succeeded.

After this:

`send s $ B.pack "AT\r"`

I do get the "\r" as a result.

But when i try `send s $ B.pack "AT+CGMI"` I get nothing

I have tried to connect with Putty and it works.

Comment: Try the [portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx) tool to make sure the commands are getting executed properly.

Comment: ˋrecv s 10 >>= printˋ should give you the first 10 bytes of whatever the device will send on the serial line. Concerning ˋsend s $ B.pack "AT+CGMI"ˋ, didn't you forget the "\r" after "CGMI" ?

Comment: Have you also verified that the serial port settings you set correspond with the serial port settings of the device you try to communicate with ? Default serial port settings for SerialPort are 9600 bps, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no parity, no flow control and 0.1 second receive timeout ? When you use ˋcommSpeed = CS2400ˋ, you only change the comm speed, not the other parameters

Comment: @zigazou Thanks for the hints. I don't know how to choose the other parameters

Comment: Ex.: `SerialPortSettings { commSpeed = CS1200, bitsPerWord = 7, stopb = One, parity = Even, flowControl = NoFlowControl, timeout = 10 }` or `defaultSerialSettings { commSpeed = CS1200, bitsPerWord = 7, stopb = One, parity = Even, flowControl = NoFlowControl, timeout = 10 }`